# How do I get data into a div without refresh?

Tags: jquery

I have some data that I want to show using JQuery but don't know how to show it. I have a search box where the user types a search term, then when it's submitted, if found, a div would be shown with the data. If the search term was not found, the div should not be shown.

I know how to do this when the page refreshes but how to do this without a page refresh. Can someone please point me to an example?

---

EDIT:

This is what I am currently using. I'm really new to JQuery so some of the examples that have already been posted seem a bit different. I'm not really sure which example would work for me.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://site.com/search.php",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    if(data.success == 1){
      alert('success');
    }else{
      alert('fail');
    }
  }
});
return false;
```

Comment: [You need AJAX](http://willgoldstone.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/ajax.jpg)

Comment: ajax. Is what you need. Look into `jQuery.ajax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (if you want to do it without a refresh). Something like this should work:

```
jQuery("#mySearchForm").submit(function() {

    var searchTerm = jQuery("#mySearchInput").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://my.url.com",
        data: searchTerm,
        dataType: "json", //assumes your return data-type is json
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           //assumes your json has a property called response
           jQuery("#myDiv").html(data.response); 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           //error-handling code
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Vivin, I'm already using ajax that points to the function that builds my data. According to your example, if I'm understanding it right, the success function outputs the html. Am I right?

Comment: @jim Yes. The success function assumes that your response is JSON (if it's not then you need to handle it accordingly -- if it's HTML, you can add it to the div directly) and updates the div with the data it gets back from the AJAX call.

Comment: jim, those parameters are standard parameters to the `success` function. You don't *have* to use them if you don't need to. Your example looks like it should work. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Vivian, I just don't know how to show the data to the user. When the user searches for the term they want, the jquery function points to my search.php page and in that file, I have a function that builds the data, if found. I can see my data in Firebug but how to get it to render to the user is my real problem. I'm assuming that your line of `jQuery("#myDiv").html(data.response);` is what does it but what exactly is the 'response'. What does the response hold?

Comment: Jim, how are you returning the data from the server side? Some JSON like this would work `{success: true, data: "I found something"}`

Comment: Yes Vivin, it is a JSOn encoded array. I'm also using a table that holds the data I want to show. Actually, they are just the table rows of the table.

Comment: All you need to do is get to data that's stored in the JSON, and display that in your div.

Comment: Holy carp.. It works Vivin. :)  Here is the issue that I am currently having. I'm building the table rows in my PHP. I'm outputting them all as a string and before I had JQuery working in this form, my PHP would simply insert the rows into the table. Now, to test your example, I've put a div with an ID of 'results' between the table where the data should sit but the data renders at the top of the page. How should I fix this?

Comment: I got it Vivin. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the html() function to load the html contents you want into a container (parent div).
    http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Thanks JP. I'll look into that now. Thanks for the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must use AJAX. Here you can find some good examples: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Either use 
[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

or

[PageMethods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

Comment: pagemethos rely on ASP.NET he may be using PHP or another server-side platform

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, the actual form input is not shown

```
<label id="name_error">Please enter between 2 - 25 legibly written characters, letters  only</label>
<div>
<ul id="display">

</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#display').hide();   
$('#name_error').hide(); 
    $('#submit').click(function() { // could be #form .submit

      var twit = $("#twitter_search").val(); //the search variable name
        if (twit == "") {
          $("label#name_error").show();
          $("input#twitter_search").focus();
          return false;
        }  
var datastring = $('#form').serialize(); 

$.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo site_url('twitter/search'); ?>", //this is the same as your Form action
   type: "POST",
   data: datastring, 
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#display').html(msg).show(1000);            
        }
    }); 
    return false;       

});
});
</script>
```

Notice the #display after the success function then look up at the top, you will see the display DIV.  BTW, the URL is a codeigniter example, yours would be different

Comment: Thanks Brad. I'm looking this over now.

Answer (score 0):

- You should bind a click event to your submit button.
- When it is clicked you should prevent default and make an ajax get with JQUery.
- According to that response you should set the html of that div.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a search form like this that works using non-AJAX:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/search" type="post">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
   <button id="searchButton" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and on post it will add a DIV, like below.

```
<div id="results">
  ...
</div>
```

Without modifying your server side code you could get this to work with AJAX by doing the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('form').submit( function() {
         var $form = $(this); // store a reference to the form
         // do an AJAX post using the form action and the data from the form
         // and get the result.
         $.post( $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
              // find the results div inside the returned html and insert
              // it in the DOM after the form element.
              $('#results',$(result)).after($form);
         });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. Because I'm a real noob with javascript, can you tell me what the difference is between your code and Vivin's above? I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @Jim - he's using javascript to grab the input and do an ajax request to a hard-coded url.  I'm simply grabbing the values from the form and serializing them and posting back to its action.  Another difference is I'm using the `post` convenience wrapper around the full-featured `ajax` call.  Finally, I am extracting the div out of the response meaning that your server side doesn't change. His example expects just the results to be delivered back which would require some code changes on the server.